# Node.js(express, mongodb) registration process

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

Hello Stackoverflow community,
I'm new to Node.js / express   and i need your help because i stuck at some problem.

I'm trying to make a registration process where the Post inputs are saved into a mongodb.
Before i wanna validate if the users email adress already exists in the database.

If i try to define a var at the db.users.find() statement the app wont work.

```
 app.post("/sign-up", function(req, res){

    var validate;

    db.users.find({email : req.body.email}, function(err, users) {
      if( err || !users){
                    validate = true;
      }else{
            validate = false;
            }
    });

    console.log(validate);

    if(validate == true){
            db.users.save({
                           title: req.body.title,
                           firstname: req.body.firstname,
                           surname: req.body.surname,
                           country : req.body.country,
                           email: req.body.email,
                           password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10)
                                       }, 
                           function(err, saved) {
                                              if( err || !saved ) console.log("User not saved");
                                              else console.log("User saved");
                                              res.location("sign-up-success");
                                              // And forward to success page
                                              res.redirect("sign-up-success");
                                            });
             }
 });
```

how the db.users.find() functions needs to look like that i can make if/else request for the db.users.save() function.

Comment: Your indentation looks messed up. I advise you to fix it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `db.users.find` is an asynchronous function. I'll suggest the following:

```
app.post("/sign-up", function(req, res){
  var validateUser = function(callback) {
    db.users.find({email : req.body.email}, function(err, users) {
      if( err || !users){
        callback(true);
      } else {
        callback(false);
      }
    });
  }
  validateUser(function(isValid) {
    if(isValid == true){
      db.users.save({
        title: req.body.title,
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        surname: req.body.surname,
        country : req.body.country,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10)
      }, function(err, saved) {
        if( err || !saved ) console.log("User not saved");
        else console.log("User saved");
        res.location("sign-up-success");
        // And forward to success page
        res.redirect("sign-up-success");
      });
    }
  })
 });
```

Comment: You code look elegant :>, how about if just write `callback(err || !users)`

Answer (score 1):

It is async problem, you can move some code to your find callback like this:

```
 app.post("/sign-up", function(req, res){
    var validate;
    db.users.find({email : req.body.email}, function(err, users) {
        if( err || !users){
            validate = true;
        }else{
            validate = false;
        }

        // your code should be here:
        console.log(validate);

        if(validate == true){
        ....
        }

    });


    // This code will print undefined, so you must move to the callback 
    // console.log(validate)
    // because the callback was not call yet
```

Comment: thanks need to test it later, for better understanding : can you tell me the reason why the code will print undefined if its not in the callback ?

Comment: because it is asynchronous, `db.users.find()` will not stop to wait for result

Comment: Thanks , i think that increased my general understanding for node.js.
So i need to do it this way on every asynchron function ?

Comment: Yes if you want to use the result from the callback, In case you have multiple level of nesting functions, let's use `async` package or something equipvalents